# Equivalent of KMP_AFFINITY=verbose for gnu and ibm openmp libraries?

Tags: gcc, g++, openmp, gnu, xlc

When using OpenMP on Intel systems, I often find it useful to set `KMP_AFFINITY=verbose,(other options...)` so the library spits out which cores my threads are actually bound to.  I find this helpful when experimenting with different thread binding options.  Currently I'm working with a Power8 system, and wondering if there's an equivalent of `KMP_AFFINITY=verbose` for the GNU and/or IBM OpenMP distributions.  In other words, how can I get information on where my threads are placed if I compile my OpenMP executable with g++ or xlc++?

Comment: Libgomp doesn't support affinity for targets such as Windows.  For  targets such as Linux where Intel openmp supports gcc openmp calls, that would be a way to accomplish what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GCC OpenMP documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html) (libgomp) says this is currently not possible:

> There is no libgomp library routine to determine whether a CPU affinity specification is in effect. As a workaround, language-specific library functions, e.g., `getenv` in C or `GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` in Fortran, may be used to query the setting of the `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` environment variable. A defined CPU affinity on startup cannot be changed or disabled during the runtime of the application.

You can try to use `GOMP_DEBUG` and see if it does what you are looking for.

Comment: `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=VERBOSE` does cause `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` to be printed, but it appears blank (`GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY = ''`) even when I set OMP_PLACES explicitly.  `export GOMP_DEBUG=1` does not add anything to the output either.  I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or I'm working with a version of libgomp that is not very talkative.

Comment: It probably prints the values of the environment variables that set the Internal Control Variables (ICV). If you set `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY`, it may print that value. Another possibility is to write yourself a function that prints that. I've done so using [sched_getaffinity](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_getaffinity). You can check this [useful example](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/143ea06851104ffaa9d3fe8de09c721d2364de64/lib/cpuset.c#L150). Maybe you can even submit a patch to libgomp that does what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping there was a solution as quick and complete as KMP_AFFINITY but at least this gives me some tools to work with.

Answer (score 1):

With xlc++, you can set the OMP_DISPLAY_ENV environment variable to TRUE or VERBOSE to get this information. Full details can be found on the [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSXVZZ_13.1.5/com.ibm.xlcpp1315.lelinux.doc/compiler_ref/omp_display_env.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I already tried OMP_DISPLAY_ENV.  The output shows environment variable values, including OMP_PLACES.  However, it does not appear to tell me exactly which cores each thread ends up bound to, the way KMP_AFFINITY does, unless I am missing something.  My goal here is to see the thread placement that results from a given combination of environment variables, so knowing the environment variables themselves is not that helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately xlc++ doesn't have something quite as convenient as KMP_AFFINITY=verbose, but if you're willing to modify your code and try out an undocumented feature in xlc++, there is a function _xlsmp_thread_binding() which will print out the CPU affinity for the calling thread. Since it's not officially supported, it may not work for you, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.